# extract pattern using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a vector of strings with the following format "IN_D44_A09_ET" and I would like to extract the number 9 using the stringr package.

I have been trying to solve it using str_extract(), but I don't get how to formulate the pattern.

```
values <- c("IN_D44_A09_CT", "XE_D34_A15_ET")
str_extract(values, "_A(\\d+)")
```

This pattern extracts "_A09" and "_A15" but what I want is "9" and "15".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehind pattern -

```
as.integer(stringr::str_extract(values, '(?<=A)\\d+'))
#[1]  9 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  try `sub`

```
sub(".*_A0*(.*)_.*","\\1",values)
#[1] "9"  "15"
```

Comment: Thanks! But Isn't there a stringr function I could use to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use `str_extract` twice. In the first `str_exract` whatever output you are getting, store it as a vector and run `str_extract` again to get the desired output.

Here's how you could do it:

```
values <- c("IN_D44_A09_CT", "XE_D34_A15_ET")
temp <- str_extract(values, "A(\\d+)")
str_extract(temp, "(\\d+)")
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to directly extract the number? something like: "_A0*(\d+)"?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(stringr)

values <- c("IN_D44_A09_CT", "XE_D34_A15_ET")

str_match(values, 'A(\\d+)')[, 2]
#> [1] "09" "15"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If we want to remove the zeros:

```r
library(stringr)

values <- c("IN_D44_A00090_CT", "XE_D34_A0015_ET")

str_match(values, 'A(\\d+)')[, 2] %>% str_replace('^0+', '')
#> [1] "90" "15"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>